# Programmatically setting setSelectedIndex does not didSelectViewController

Tags: ios4

In my iOS App when I am setting setSelectedIndex it does not call 
the following function

```
(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [UITabBarControllerDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW1):

> `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`
>
> "[..]  it is called only in response to user taps in the tab bar and is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically."

Therefore I suggest you find another way to achieve the desired functionality.

One option is to move whatever logic you have in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` to another method in your view controller, and call that method both in the delegate method (above), and in your code that runs `setSelectedIndex` on your UITabBarController instance.

Comment: Not without seeing the context of your question. You need to either create a new method in your class and call that when you call `setSelectedIndex`, or just include whatever logic directly where you you call `setSelectedIndex`. In summary `setSelectedIndex` will never trigger `didSelectViewController`, nor should you try to call that delegate method programmatically. You need to think of an alternative solution.

Comment: Implemented but i am getting a crash now
2012-08-13 16:44:12.979 iOSFileShare[33922:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from <UINavigationController: 0x560ba00> to <UINavigationController: 0xab12820> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Whoops, looks like you've got a bug! This looks like something different. I suggest you make another description describing the issue (with code!) if you can't work it out :)

Also if my response answered your question can you please accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: No way Hosè! You should make a new question - besides there are much smarter people than me on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to respond whenever the tab changes regardless of whether it comes from a tap, I recommend overriding setSelectedIndex:

```
-(void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex
{
    [super setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];
    [self handleSelectionChanged];
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self handleSelectionChanged];
}

- (void)handleSelectionChanged
{
    // Do something
}
```